# display json file in html with php ajax or php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hey guys if I have gotten json file from webservice what would be the best way to display it in my html. Should I use php to display the content or ajax. If php how would I do that.

This is a sample of my json file

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "title": "Brick Mansions",
        "released": "2014",
        "restricted": "12 \u00e1ra",
        "imdb": "6.0\/10  5,532 atkv.",
        "imdbLink": "http:\/\/www.imdb.com\/title\/tt1430612",
        "image": "http:\/\/kvikmyndir.is\/images\/poster\/9260_500.jpg",
        "showtimes": [
            {
                "theater": "Laugar\u00e1sb\u00ed\u00f3",
                "schedule": [
                    "20:00",
                    "22:00"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "How to Train your Dragon 2",
```

The contents is in an array called $movies as you can see in my php file

```
<?php
    $service_url ='http://apis.is/cinema';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) {
     $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
     die('Error occured during curl exec:'. var_export($info));
     }
   curl_close($curl);

   //get file and insert it into json file
   $movies = json_encode(json_decode($curl_response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   file_put_contents('json/data.json', $movies);
   ?>
```

I've been trying to put in my index.php page like so and without any luck. This is problably very ease but I'm new in the backend.

This is my index.php file

```
<body>
<?php include 'php/response.php';?>
<?php echo "$movies"; ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="movies" style="background-color:green;">
        <?php if (is_array($movies)): ?>    
            <?php foreach($movies as $movie): ?>
                <?php echo $movie['title']; ?>  
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see my the array $movie prints on the page but I cant seem to print only the title and so on. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why can you print only `title` - what's the problem with the other array elements? And why do you do the following: `echo "$movies";`?

Comment: No the point is I cant print title and the echo $movies was just a test to display the json content. I want to be able only to display for example the title og the image and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the json file to something PHP can understand i.e an array.

Also there is no need to wrap each PHP line in `<?php.. ?>` if you have more than one line of code just use it once to turn on the interpreter and once to turn it off. It will make your code so much more easy to read and debug.

```
<body>
<?php include 'php/response.php';?>
<?php 
    echo "$movies";                 // this echos a text string 
    $movys = json_decode($movies);  // convert json string to an object

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="movies" style="background-color:green;">
<?php 
    if (is_array($movys->results)): 
        foreach($movys->results as $movie):
           echo $movie->title;
        endforeach;
    endif;
?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Okey I will try it and let you know

Comment: no it didn't work but thanks anyway any other ideas?

Comment: Do me a favor and do a print_r($movys) just after the `$movys = json_decode($movies);`

Comment: I think I see my woops, I changed the answer

Comment: Yepp I done that but it gives me a  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\Movies\frontpage.php on line 24

Comment: Add the print_r($movys) to your question please

Comment: okey I hava added the print                                       $movys = json_decode($movies);print_r($movys); and it print something like this stdClass .....Object ( [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Brick Mansions [released] => 2014.......

Comment: Okey thanks alot for your help. You saved my day it worked. So if I would like to display lets showtimes I would do like echo $movie->showtimes ??? But again thank you

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again. But how would i be able to get showtimes->theater and showtimes->schedule from json?                     <?php foreach($movys->results->showtimes as $showtime): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $showtime->theater; ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: `$movie->showtimes['theatre']` and then `$movie->showtimes['schedule'][0]` and `$movie->showtimes['schedule'][1]` for the showtimes